# Generate IP from variable

Tags: bash, ip-address

I am trying to remove the multiple IP entries from a file based on the IP range that I set.

Ex of the file:

15.12.168.192
13.13.168.192
23.12.168.192
23.15.168.192
etc...

I would like to set only the RANGE area, below the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# RANGE 
START=192.168.12
END=192.168.13


##collecting the last two digit from START and END
first=`echo $START | sed 's/^.*\(.\{2\}\)$/\1/'`
last=`echo $END | sed 's/^.*\(.\{2\}\)$/\1/'`

## echo both
echo $first
echo $last

for ip in 192.168.1.{$first..$last}; do
echo "$ip"

## conversion of the IPs.
echo $ip | sed -e '/\n/!G;s/\([^.]*\)\.\(.*\n\)/&\2.\1/;//D;s/\n//'
done
```

Even if there is still the final step against the file (grep -v) - I am already stuck at this stage; I know that this is one a syntax to figure....

This is the line :

```
for ip in 192.168.1.{$first..$last}; do
echo "$ip"
```

This is the use of `$first` and `$last` to generate each IPs that gives to me trouble with.

Comment: `first` can be set more simply with `first=${START##*.}`; similarly for `last`.

Comment: A more readable way to reverse the octets is `IFS=. read a b c d <<<"$ip"; echo "$d.$c.$b.$a"`.

Answer (score 1):

`{12..45}` only works with literals, you cannot use variables. If there is only one pair of braces, though, no need for the expansion:

```
for fourth in $( seq $first $last) ; do
    echo 192.168.1.$fourth
done
```

Comment: The reason is that the shell does brace expansion *before* parameter expansion: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

Comment: without calling out to `seq`, you can do a C-like for-loop using arithmetic expression: `for ((i=$first; i<=$last; i++)); ...`